# Clear asp.net form on jquery ui dialog cross click

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jquery-ui modal with gridview to add/update records in an asp.net application. The user can click on the cross to close the modal? I want to clear the modal content (including any ViewState). So far I have used the following code:

```
$('#editData').dialog({
    ....
    close: function () {
    **// Here I want to clear the form**
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just reset the form:

```
 $('#formId').trigger("reset");

$('#editData').dialog({
    ....
    close: function () {
    // Here I want to clear the form
    $('#formId').trigger("reset");
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pNALN/1/

You can also use `document.forms["formId"].reset();` if you wanted to achieve it via JavasScript.

Comment: @user2227467 - did you change `formId` to the form id you're using? Check the JS Fiddle it works.

Comment: yes I am using the correct form name. Still it didn't work. I also tried the second solution but i get an error **"unable to get value of property reset"**